# Main thread exits before workers

Tags: netty

In some of my experiments with Netty the main thread exits before all the I/O threads are complete. I've been using a CountDownLatch to prevent this. Is this the right approach? Is there a standard approach for avoiding this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a countdown latch is a good approach.  But I don't know if I'd call it a standard.  Shut down is, in general, a hard problem.  Most apps I've worked on have used a grab bag of different approaches for shutting down their various components.

Comment: I'm actually trying to keep them from shutting down prematurely.

Comment: I'm a little confused...  _"the main thread exits before all the I/O threads are complete"_  Is this not the case?  If you're trying to prevent the main thread from exiting before the workers finish, then a countdown latch is a good approach.  If not, then please clarify.

Comment: This works ok. But I have another example based on the proxy example code where it seems not to be a problem and no latch is required. So I'm the one thats confused :-)

Comment: Concurrency is nothing if not confusing.  I'd try posting another question with the code you're wondering about.

Answer (score 0):

You could just wait until the channel you created is closed.  For example:

```
public static void main(St ring[] args) throws Exception {
    ChannelFactory f = ...;
    try {
        ...
        Channel ch = bootstrap.connect().sync();
        ch.getCloseFuture().sync(); // Wait until the channel is closed.
    } finally {
        f.releaseExternalResources();
    }
}
```